# Correct understanding of basis and span

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering if my understanding is correct here.

Let's say I have a matrix A:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\ -3 & 7 & 0 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$

I find that the redued row echelon form, rref:

$rref(A)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Now I am not entirely sure what to do. Is this correct:

$basis(A)=span(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix})$

The reason I am unsure is because I have not seen a column with all zeros before, just a row, which means a free variable.

Also, would it be correct to say that "$basis(A)$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$"?

Comment: Yes, it is correct: it's easy to see the rows' dimension is three so also the column's dimension is three, and since these are 3-dimensional column vectors then their span is all of $\;F^3\;$ , or $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ , if you're working on the reals.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick reply, Timbuc!

Comment: @Timbuc No, it's not correct. It is correct to say that the *columns* of $A$ span $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @5xum That's what I assumed the OP meant (read my comment) , but the point is taken.

Comment: @Akitirija I thought that's what you said, but since the OP is obviously confused about what certain terms mean, I don't think it's correct to say "yes it's correct", when they clearly did not use the proper terminology...

Comment: It's true that I am confused about these terms, thank you, 5xum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Basis of a matrix" does not actually make any sense.  You should say "basis for the column space of the matrix".

Subject to that, your answer for the basis is correct, but only by accident.  You should take not the columns of the reduced matrix, but the corresponding columns from the original matrix.  For your question that's columns 1, 2 and 4, so you get the basis
$$\left\{\pmatrix{3\cr-3\cr0\cr},\pmatrix{-3\cr7\cr0\cr},\pmatrix{0\cr-3\cr5\cr}\right\}\ .$$
In this case it happens that your answer is also correct (both are bases for $\Bbb R^3$) but as I said, that is more or less an accident - in a different case, taking columns from the reduced matrix would frequently give an incorrect answer.

Comment: Thank you, David. So how would you go about to find the basis of the column space of a matrix in a correct way? I think the terminology is killing me a little bit here, as @5xum pointed out.

Comment: What you have done is exactly correct, except for the final step of going back to the columns of the original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight misunderstanding of the terms *span* and *basis*. Here are the definitions:

> For a subset $S$ of a linear space $L$, the *span* of the set $S$ is *the smallest (in terms of inclusion) linear subspace of $L$ which includes all elements from $S$*. In the case when $S$ is finite, $S=\{x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n\}$, the span of $S$ is the set of all linear combinations of vectors from $S$.

This means that the *span* of one set is some other set.

On the other hand:

> A set $B$ is the basis of a linear space $L$ iff (a) $L$ is equal to the span of $B$ and (b) $B$ is linearly independent.

This means that whether or not a set $B$ is a basis is *the property* of a given set.